# How can I get the link to YouTube Channel from Video Page?

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, youtube, webdriver

I've been trying to get the link to the YouTube channel from the Video Page. However, I couldn't find the element of the link. With Inspector, it is obvious that the link is right here as the following picture.
[image]

With the code `'a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string'`, I tried to get the link through the following code.

```
! pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
! pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedrive\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6Cc2R2jK6s')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
links = soup.select('a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

However, no matter I used `links = soup.select('a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string')` or `links = soup.find('a', class_='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-owner-renderer')`, it did not print anything. Someone please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
links = soup.select('a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string')
```

In `Selenium` if I would do:

```
links = drvier.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string')
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. I just replace it with `links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#text > a')` as you recommended.